# How bar ends helps in reducing handle bar vibrations on motorcycle?

Tags: motorcycle, vibration, weight, handlebars

I understand the basics of the resonance and how it works.

Now the case is, there are vibrations from my motorcycle engine which then gets transferred to the handlebar.
The motorcycle came with weighted bar ends (210gms each side) shown as number 2 in the given photo and it helps in reducing the handlebar vibrations a lot.

I thought why not add more weight,so I added additional weighted bar ends (180gms), shown as number 1 in the photo, along with the original bar ends (210 gms).

*Ideally the vibrations should reduce, but what I observed was, drastic increase in the handlebar vibrations.*

Anything I did wrong here? Shouldn't it be more the weight of the handlebar, lesser the vibrations?

[image]

Comment: If you get the extra masses right (wrong) then you can get closer to the natural frequency ie increase the problem not reduce it....

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @SolarMike how will I find the correct value of weights required to move it away from the natural frequency.

Comment: Trial and error... now try half the original value etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding weight will change the resonant frequency of the handlebars, yes. But if the weight you added made that resonance closer to the problem frequency, then it can amplify them dramatically.

It is always worth experimenting with weights, but also [steering dampers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7mU5KStueQ). Altering both can help you get rid of unwanted vibrations.

I'd be tempted to suggest it may not be the engine vibration that is the main problem, after all you can always ride at different rpm. Is there a specific frequency that issues happen? Look at the rest of the bike as well.

Comment: Hi @Rory Alsop Thanks for the reply. So adding and reducing (weights), both can take it closer to the problem frequency? So how should I find the problem frequency. Is hit and trial the only method, where I try different weights. And how should I achieve dampening? By wrapping the handlebar or by using damping inserts in the handle bar?

Comment: @Coffee_lover - I have edited to use the most common name - yes, steering dampers or steering stabilizers - and I have added a youtube link to show when you might need them

Comment: I added a rubber washer between the OEM bar ends and the barkbusters weighted bar ends. It has improved vibrations compared to the (OEM bar ends) only but not a lot. Though the drastic effect that I observed has gone. My question is, placing a rubber between 2 bar ends will still work right (as we are still increasing the weight of the handlebar) ? Now should I increase the rubber or the weight?

Comment: There is literally no answer. It could be that you should increase it, it could be that you should decrease it. The only way to check on your bike is trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Me too facing the problem of vibrations at the handlebar when I changed the stock one with an after market handlebar which is heavier in weight.Fixed the same with stock bar end weights, But the Handle bar tends to vibrate at 3000 rpm which creates numbness in fingers when I go for a long ride. Realized this is because of a heavier handlebar with a heavier bar end. So I removed the bar end weights on both sides. Now the vibration is not there.